# SSL_read failing with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error

Tags: openssl, ssl

We have implemented tls using openssl. While downloading larger data from server getting `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` error after receiving the some data. For smaller files I am not getting this error, able to download without any error. ERR_get_error() is showing zero for larger files.

We are using linux and c++ framework. How to find reason for the failure? What could be the reason for failure? kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: You might try the OpenSSL user list. They sometimes get questions like this, and explain how to get more information, some possible causes and some possible fixes. As it stands, there's probably not enough information for someone to help you. [SSL_read failed SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mailing.openssl.users/SSL_read$20failed$20SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL$20error).

Answer (score 19):

SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL indicates that some problem happened with the underlying I/O (Should be TCP in this case). So, you can try checking with errno.

OpenSSL help says:

> **SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL**
>
> Some I/O error occurred. The OpenSSL error queue may
> contain more information on the error. If the error queue is empty
> (i.e. ERR_get_error() returns 0), ret can be used to find out more
> about the error: If ret == 0, an EOF was observed that violates the
> protocol. If ret == -1, the underlying BIO reported an I/O error (for
> socket I/O on Unix systems, consult errno for details).

Comment: Thanks, ERR_get_error() returns 0, so in this case what is the protocol viloation? what might be the problem?

Comment: There might not be any protocol violation at all. Mostly the other side would have closed the socket.

Comment: Ok. what can be done client side in case if server closes socket immediatly after transfering the data? I am using openssl for tls implementation.

Comment: I am using Linux environment after receving the SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error I have printed errorno and it showing zero as errorno.

Comment: @pavan I've encountered very similar symptoms - did you find out the cause?

Comment: @frankster I think you and pavan should check the server for error codes if the client doesn't get any detailed info on why the server shut down.

Comment: @pavan I am facing the same problem. Can you please let us know if you found the reason for failure ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I found the issue to be my companies firewall blocking the requests. Go home and it should work

Answer (score 6):

If you look into the source code for `SSL_get_error()` you'll see, that it returns `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` whenever it not sure what exactly happened. It's basically default return code for "unknown" case.

For example, in my case (doing non-blocking IO with BIO):

```
int buf;
const int n = SSL_read(ssl, &buf, 0);
const int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, n);
const int st = ERR_get_error();
```

When `n` is 0, `err` will be `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` just because. However `st` still will be 0 indicating that there was no real error. `SSL_read` just returned 0 because 0 bytes was written to the `buf`.

However, look for `errno` / `WSAGetLastError()` values after the call for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you call SSL_read() with a buffer size of 0. I have made the following mistake using SSL_pending():

```
int waitForReadFd = nBuf < bufSize;

if (waitForReadFd)
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

// ...
// select

int doReadFd = FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds) || SSL_pending(ssl);

if (doReadFd)
    n = SSL_read(ssl, buf, bufSize - nBuf);
```

If `nBuf == bufSize` SSL_read() will be called with a buffer size of 0 what leads to SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with errno == 0.

Changing the doReadFd check will avoid this problem:

```
int doReadFd = FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds) || nBuf < bufSize && SSL_pending(ssl);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the network connection being cut and the server re-setting.

Just make sure the connection is Ok before downloading the data.

A similar problem can be seen here when using vagrant.

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9612

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error in a Go application. We were using a third party library to connect to underlying openssl library from Go. While reading data the third party library was converting the length of buffer/data to be read to C.int which is 32bits. For large data >= 2GB this lead to overflow and a negative value being passed to C.SSL_read function.
It raised SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error in that case.