# OpenSSL- Linux System requirements

Tags: c, linux, openssl, compatibility

Unfortunately, I was unable to find an answer to my question on google.

I have 2 devices with very similar hardware. On 1 device my SSL code runs flawlessly, on the second it doesn't. The major difference between both devices is the linux kernel version. 
The code works on `2.6.24.6` but not `2.4.21` (Error when attempting to do handshake using ssl_connect() the error is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL). My guess is, the latter kernel version is not supported.

Could someone point me out to where I can find more information about minimum system requirements for OpenSSL ?
In case, kernel `2.4.21` is not supported, is there any other library I could use?

Comment: Google found some documents. What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686398/ssl-read-failing-with-ssl-error-syscall-error for example?

Comment: It seems to me the major difference is the version of OpenSSL you are using on the different devices. What do you get when you call `SSLeay_version`? Are they the same on both devices? If you are compiling against 1.0.1, and one of the devices has 1.0.0 or 0.9.8 installed, then you are going to have problems. See [OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.html).

Comment: @jww I've never used any other version beside 1.0.1f . The reason I'm suspecting unsupported kernel version is because I get SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL before any traffic can be observed through wireshark and perror returns `file not found`. This happens on 4 different devices having the same `kernel 2.4.21`. I'll check `SSLeasy_version` tomorrow once I get to the office.

Comment: @hek2mgl the issue represented in the question happens after the initial handshake. My issue is before the handshake takes place. Something seems to be missing on the devices where it doesn't work, since `perror` prints `file not found`.

Answer (score 2):

To see a list of supported OSes and platforms, run `Configure` with a bogus a argument:

```
$ ./Configure XXX
Configuring for XXX
Usage: Configure [no-<cipher> ...] [enable-<cipher> ...] [experimental-<cipher> ...] [-Dxxx] [-lxxx] [-Lxxx] [-fxxx] [-Kxxx] [no-hw-xxx|no-hw] [[no-]threads] [[no-]shared] [[no-]zlib|zlib-dynamic] [no-asm] [no-dso] [no-krb5] [sctp] [386] [--prefix=DIR] [--openssldir=OPENSSLDIR] [--with-xxx[=vvv]] [--test-sanity] os/compiler[:flags]

pick os/compiler from:
BC-32 BS2000-OSD BSD-generic32 BSD-generic64 BSD-ia64 BSD-sparc64 BSD-sparcv8 
BSD-x86 BSD-x86-elf BSD-x86_64 Cygwin Cygwin-pre1.3 DJGPP MPE/iX-gcc OS2-EMX 
OS390-Unix QNX6 QNX6-i386 ReliantUNIX SINIX SINIX-N UWIN VC-CE VC-WIN32 
VC-WIN64A VC-WIN64I aix-cc aix-gcc aix3-cc aix64-cc aix64-gcc android 
android-armv7 android-x86 aux3-gcc beos-x86-bone beos-x86-r5 bsdi-elf-gcc cc 
cray-j90 cray-t3e darwin-i386-cc darwin-ppc-cc darwin64-ppc-cc 
darwin64-x86_64-cc dgux-R3-gcc dgux-R4-gcc dgux-R4-x86-gcc dist gcc hpux-cc 
hpux-gcc hpux-ia64-cc hpux-ia64-gcc hpux-parisc-cc hpux-parisc-cc-o4 
hpux-parisc-gcc hpux-parisc1_1-cc hpux-parisc1_1-gcc hpux-parisc2-cc 
hpux-parisc2-gcc hpux64-ia64-cc hpux64-ia64-gcc hpux64-parisc2-cc 
hpux64-parisc2-gcc hurd-x86 iphoneos-cross irix-cc irix-gcc irix-mips3-cc 
irix-mips3-gcc irix64-mips4-cc irix64-mips4-gcc linux-alpha+bwx-ccc 
linux-alpha+bwx-gcc linux-alpha-ccc linux-alpha-gcc linux-aout linux-armv4 
linux-elf linux-generic32 linux-generic64 linux-ia32-icc linux-ia64 
linux-ia64-ecc linux-ia64-icc linux-ppc linux-ppc64 linux-sparcv8 
linux-sparcv9 linux-x86_64 linux32-s390x linux64-s390x linux64-sparcv9 mingw 
mingw64 ncr-scde netware-clib netware-clib-bsdsock netware-clib-bsdsock-gcc 
netware-clib-gcc netware-libc netware-libc-bsdsock netware-libc-bsdsock-gcc 
netware-libc-gcc newsos4-gcc nextstep nextstep3.3 osf1-alpha-cc osf1-alpha-gcc 
purify qnx4 rhapsody-ppc-cc sco5-cc sco5-gcc solaris-sparcv7-cc 
solaris-sparcv7-gcc solaris-sparcv8-cc solaris-sparcv8-gcc solaris-sparcv9-cc 
solaris-sparcv9-gcc solaris-x86-cc solaris-x86-gcc solaris64-sparcv9-cc 
solaris64-sparcv9-gcc solaris64-x86_64-cc solaris64-x86_64-gcc sunos-gcc 
tandem-c89 tru64-alpha-cc uClinux-dist uClinux-dist64 ultrix-cc ultrix-gcc 
unixware-2.0 unixware-2.1 unixware-7 unixware-7-gcc vos-gcc vxworks-mips 
vxworks-ppc405 vxworks-ppc60x vxworks-ppc750 vxworks-ppc750-debug 
vxworks-ppc860 vxworks-ppcgen vxworks-simlinux ...

NOTE: If in doubt, on Unix-ish systems use './config'.
```

Comment: I know about the platforms, but I'm interested in Linux kernel versions. Getting 'file or directory not found` on `2.4.21` makes me suspect something is missing or incompatible in `2.4.21`.

Comment: You're probably barking up the wrong tree. OpenSSL has run on nearly all (all?) Linux kernel version since the 1990s. Since you are talking about devices, you should probably investigate Android-isms. In that case, your version of OpenSSL 1.0.1 is *not* used. Rather, you get Android's 0.9.8 because its already mapped in from the Zygote fork.